# Convert between timezone in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I am reading time from the DB in format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a z` now I want to display this time in user local timezone. So my question are:

1. Where should it be done client side or server side?
2. Is there build in lib for this purpose?

**UPDATE**
So I decide to do conversion in server, therefore I have method definition as following with parameter date from server and time zone offset of the client time.

```
public String convertToLocalDateTime(Date dateFromDB, Integer offSetMins) {
  //1. dbDateInUTC = Convert dateFromDB to UTC
  //2. return offSetMins + dbDateInUTC;
}
```

I am not sure how I can do step (1). Any suggestion?

Comment: How is the time stored in the DB? As a time with timezone field? How do you retrieve it in your Java code (as what type)?

Comment: What do you mean by "client side" exactly? What is the client here?

Comment: After reading the date from DB it will be automatically converted to the server local time. So it should be ready to display in server time-zone. For the user you can convert the time to the user zone before sending date, but you need to know user time-zone. You can check if user request has that info available. If it is not available then send your time with your time-zone for the user to convert.

Comment: [Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is a commonly used library for handling dates and times in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure user gets it's timezone you can do it at client side, for this you can use a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).

Just get the date of the server, transform it in long:

```
Date d = // date from server
long milliseconds = d.getTime();
```

Send to client and get the offset:

> **The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time**. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example, if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600 will be returned. Daylight saving time prevents this value from being a constant even for a given locale.

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Then you just have to get the corrected date **1 minute = 60.000 milliseconds** :

```
var dateInMilliseconds = dateFromServer - (offset * 60000);
```

Also, if as [@jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) suggested you want to do it telling server client's timezone, get the `offset` and send it to java to transform the date:

```
long offsetMillis = offset * 60000;
Date d = new Date(offsetMillis);
```

Comment: Well, or tell the server the time zone... there are various options here.

Comment: OP is asking about Java. Why are you talking about Javascript libraries?

Comment: because client side?

Answer (score 1):

In my practice, to avoid complecity and confusion, it is better to:

1. For operating and persisting dates within the application use UTC timezone.
2. Display date/time to the end user, using the local timezone.

Thus, server side all dates/times in UTC and client-side in local TZ.

Comment: Plus one. Better still if you drop GMT for UTC.